# How to make guice injection work with Akka 2.5

Tags: java, akka

I have a Akka setup which is more or less following tree structure. I tired to follow the http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/actors.html (sub topic dependency injection).

But as its shown in the call

```
  final ActorRef myActor = getContext().actorOf(
    Props.create(DependencyInjector.class, applicationContext, "TheActor"),
      "TheActor");
```

the value applicationContext should be available before creating the actor. I would prefer to put guice injectors inside the `DependencyInjector` class.

This is not a problem in root layer. But once its going deeper, I have to keep passing many variables which are required in the leaf layers (but not in intermediate layers). What would be the nice way to handle this issue ?

Comment: An example showing the problem would help clarify.